# How to calculate rotated image position after zoom

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have looked through a lot of answers for similar problems but was not able to find any that actually seem to work for me.  My problem is very simple, I have two images occupying the exact same spot, however they are at different angles from each other. When I zoom in or out, the images should still occupy the same spot as each other, however, the rotated image always moves.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<style>
    .building {
        width:40px;
        height:40px;
        position:absolute;
        left:100px;
        top:100px;
    }
</style>
<div style="display:flex;justifty-content:space-evenly;width:80%;">
    <div id="container" style="position:relative;width:200px;height:200px;border:1px solid red;">
        <img src="image1.png" class="building">
        <img src="image2.png" class="building" style="transform:rotate(45deg);">
    </div>
    <div>Scale:<input id="scale" type="text" onChange="changeScale(this.value)"></div>
</div>
<script>
    var oldScale = 1;
    
    function changeScale(_scale) {
        var zoom = _scale;
        var zdelta = (_scale/oldScale);
        oldScale=_scale;
        
        var w = $("#container").width();
        var h = $("#container").height();
        $("#container").width(w*zdelta);
        $("#container").height(h*zdelta);
        
        $(".building").each(function() {
            var p = $(this).position();
            w = $(this).width()*zdelta;
            h = $(this).height()*zdelta;
            var r = getCurrentRotation(this);
        
            $(this).css({top: (p.top*zdelta), left: (p.left*zdelta)});
            $(this).width(w);
            $(this).height(h);
        });
    }
</script>
```

I have tried to use the following to adjust the rotated image:

`$(this).css({top: (p.top*zdelta)+( (h/2)*Math.cos(r) ), left: (p.left*zdelta)+( (w/2)*Math.sin(r) ) });`

as well as

```
function GetArrowLeftShift(w,degrees )
    {
        var result = (w / 2) * Math.cos( degrees * Math.PI / 180 );
        return result;
    }
```

as well as Math.sqrt( Math.pow(w/2,2)+Math.pow(h/2,2) );

Note: I have tried to make the problem easier by using the center position of the square with equal sized images. The real application with have the images in any position, and their sizes will vary but they will need to retain their exact positions in relation to the other images in the square.

Comment: `$(this).css({top: (p.top*zdelta)+( (h/2)*Math.cos(r) ), left: (p.left*zdelta)+( (w/2)*Math.sin(r) ) });`  comes the closest to being right, but its still off by 8.889 when quadrupled in size. May javascript by chance be truncating a value?

Answer (score 0):

So, since I could never find a good mathematical solution to solve this problem, I have ended up doing the following:

```
var r = getCurrentRotation(this);
$(this).css({transform:"rotate(0deg)"});
var p = $(this).position();
var w = $(this).width()*zdelta;
var h = $(this).height()*zdelta;
$(this).css({top:p.top*zdelta,left:p.left*zdelta,transform:"rotate(+"r+"deg)"});
```

In essence, I set the rotation to 0, then scale the image and reposition the image and set its rotation back to its original angle.